# In the Guy Pearce (2002) Time Machine did the Uber Morlock have telekinesis?

Tags: the-time-machine-2002

He apparently simply extended his hand to pull the professor to him. And whether this was real or due to mind control, the fight between them really would have been absurdly one-sided, a big hole in the plot I think.